# Version check of python

Tags: c++, c

I need to check if installed Python version is 32 bit or 64 bit using my C program running in Windows 10, not in my Python program.

How can I check the Python architecture using C code?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Which language? You wrote "C" but your tags say also C++ and C++CLI

Comment: Any of these 3 languages are okay, basically I need the answer.

Comment: What have you tried and what is your difficulty?

Comment: I need to call some python code in my c++/cli  program only if the system contains 64 bit version of python. So first I am supposed to check whether the python is of 64 bit or not.  If 64 bit then I need to embedded the python code.

Comment: *which* Python?

Comment: basically python 3, but problem is not with python. Instead how to know the python architecture using C/ C++ or c++/cli

Comment: There can be several versions of Python in different directories. You could have 32-bit and 64-bit versions of python2.x or python3.x.

Comment: @archana You could try  `cmd = "python3 -c \"import sys ; import platform; print (sys.version) ; print( platform.platform())\";` . and then `fh = popen(cmd, "r");`. Then you can read the required information from the `fh` file handle. Works on Linux, please note that the invocation syntax could be a bit different on a Windows system. Do not forget to call `pclose(fh);` when done.

Comment: @jpmarinier Thanks for your suggestion. I could use system() instead of popen()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *cmd = "python -c \"import sys,platform ;exit(platform.architecture()[0]==\"32bit\")\""
int ret = system(cmd);
```

ret will be 1 for 32 bit and 0 for 64

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Only diff is instead of "32bit" I have to write as '32bit'